# Logout from facebook, when logout from rails APP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, facebook-authentication

In my rails app, i have been using **omni-auth 1.4.0** for the facebook integration. So after i done the expire access token issue, when i logout from my app, the facebook will automatically logout.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to logout from facebook also after you logout from your rails app then, in your logout action you should add the logout call to facebook like :

```
redirect_to "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=#{redirection_url}&access_token=#{fb_access_token}"
```

In the above url

redirection_url means ---> the url where you want to get redirect after facebook logs out

fb_access_token means ---> access token generated after facebook login

Add this line at the end of logout action of your rails app along with the logic for your rails app logout.